# avoid auto-change of width of jQuery accordion

Tags: jquery-ui, width, accordion

How can I avoid auto-resizing of jQuery Accordion headers if I visit content of accordion ?

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#dvAccordion").accordion(
            { autoHeight: false,
                collapsible: true
            }
        );
     });
</script>
```

Markup:

```
    <div id="dvAccordion">
    <h5><a href="#fragment1"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAccordionRC" Text="Hi" meta:resourcekey="lblAccordionRC"  ></asp:Label></a></h5>
        <div id="fragment1">
            <div style=" height:10px; width:200%; background-color:Blue;"></div>                
        </div>
    <h5><a href="#fragment2"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAccodionUNC" Text="How"  meta:resourcekey="lblAccodionUNC"></asp:Label></a></h5>               
        <div id="fragment2">
            How are You ?
        </div>        
    </div>
```

The first accordion contains a wider div than second. If I click on first accordion, a resize of header of accordions takes place. Then If I click second accordion, it shrinks back. It makes a bad visualization of page in end user. **How can I remove this auto-resize ?**

Comment: your question is not clear enough.
please try to explain more and maybe add some code.

Comment: What exactly is the behaviour you want? Do you want the accordion to always have the same width? => overflow:auto; on the fragments.

Comment: @maenu: Yes you are right. I want to keep a constant width.

Comment: Hm, I can't reproduce the described behaviour ([see jsFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/mPz8Y/)). In this example, the accordion seems to behave as you want it. Maybe it has something to do with the versions of jQuery and UI you are using?

Comment: @maenu: Yea. Its working on machine also. But the real code which contains a lot of elements such as ASP.NET GridView, Text Boxes etc makes a auto resize of the accordion. Any possibilities ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421122/width-of-jquery-accordion

Comment: @mmk_open: I think I have the same problem: I want the accordion to use it's *maximum* width regardless the shown content, right? Did you get a solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 5):

set the width of the accordion using css

```
<div id="dvAccordion" style="width:300px;">
```

for some reason, setting width in html doesn't seem to work properly with the jquery.

Comment: <div id="dvAccordion" style="width:300px;">

Comment: You could also try wrapping it with another div and then setting its width. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15991300/2744444).